# auto-populate an email table body: subscript out of range

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling

I'm currently creating a macro that will auto-populate an email table body and add a specific amount of rows depending on how many errors are present in the data. This **doesn't** pull from a range from an excel worksheet, it is hard coded into the macro. I'm trying to add a specific amount of rows into the table depending on the ***NumberOfErrors*** variable. I've created a long list of IF Then, Else If's to cater for each amount of rows needed but keep getting the "run-time error '9': subscript out of range" error even though the **StrBody** has worked for me in the past. Can anyone advise me why I'm getting this error? TIA

```
    Sub DeltaQueryEmailToo()

    Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim OutlookMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim strBody As String, ErrorArray() As String
    Dim NumberOfErrors As Integer, i As Integer

    Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set OutlookMail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    'Finding the number of errors from the 'Error' field by looking for '/'
    NumberOfErrors = Len(Range("H4").Value) - Len(Replace(Range("H4").Value, "//", ""))

    If NumberOfErrors = 0 Then
        If Len(Range("H4").Value) > 0 Then
            NumberOfErrors = 1
        Else
            NumberOfErrors = 0
        End If
    End If

    'Resizing Array, 1 column is payload error, seconf is expected value
    ReDim ErrorArray(1 To 2, 1 To NumberOfErrors)

    i = 1

    'All errors to be queried with payload error, querie title and expected answer
    If Range("N2").Value = "Delta" Then
        If InStr(1, Range("H4").Value, "Max Interrogation Cycle", 1) > 0 Then
            ErrorArray(1, i) = "Max Interrogatn Cycle"
            ErrorArray(2, i) = "365"
            i = i + 1

        ElseIf InStr(1, Range("H4").Value, "AMI", 1) > 0 Then
          ErrorArray(1, i) = "Rim AMI"
          ErrorArray(2, i) = "Yes"
          i = i + 1

        ElseIf InStr(1, Range("H4").Value, "Action", 1) > 0 Then
          ErrorArray(1, i) = "Action"
          ErrorArray(2, i) = "Yes"
          i = i + 1

    End If


    'Contents of email
    If NumberOfErrors = 0 Then
        strBody = "<table>" & _
            "<tr>" & _
        "<th>ICP</th><th>Error Field in payload</th><th>Expected Value</th><th>Re-trigger                 required (Y/N)</th><th>Notes</th>" & _
            "</tr>" & _
            "<tr>" & _
                "<td>-</td><td>-</td><td>-</td><td>-</td><td>-</td>" & _
            "</tr>" & _
            "</table>"
    
    ElseIf NumberOfErrors = 1 Then
        strBody = "<html><style>" & _
        "table {width: 60%;}" & _
            "th, td {text-align: center; padding: 5px; border-collapse: collapse; border: 1px solid}" & _
            "th {background-color: #02A4E1; color: white; color: black}" & _
        "</style><body>" & _
        "<p>Hi Team,<br><br>Please do the needful (below table) at earliest & advise the same         : <br><br></p>" & _
        "<table><tr>" & _
                "<th>ICP</th><th>Error Field in payload</th><th>Expected Value</th><th>Re-        trigger required (Y/N)</th><th>Notes</th>" & _
            "</tr>" & _
            "<tr>" & _
                "<td>" & Range("D4").Value & "</td><td>" & ErrorArray(1, 1) & "</td><td>" & ErrorArray(2, 1) & "</td><td>-</td><td>-</td>" & _
            "</tr>" & _
            "<tr>" & _
            "</tr></table><style>" & _
        "th, td {" & _
                "text-align: left; padding: 5px; border-collapse: collapse; border:0}" & _
        "<p>Kind regards,<br></p></body></html>"

    ElseIf NumberOfErrors = 2 Then
        strBody = "<html><style>" & _
        "table {width: 60%;}" & _
            "th, td {text-align: center; padding: 5px; border-collapse: collapse; border: 1px solid}" & _
            "th {background-color: #02A4E1; color: white; color: black}" & _
        "</style><body>" & _
        "<p>Hi Team,<br><br>Please do the needful (below table) at earliest & advise the same : <br><br></p>" & _
        "<table><tr>" & _
                "<th>ICP</th><th>Error Field in payload</th><th>Expected Value</th><th>Re-trigger required (Y/N)</th><th>Notes</th>" & _
            "</tr>" & _
            "<tr>" & _
                "<td>" & Range("D4").Value & "</td><td>" & ErrorArray(1, 1) & "</td><td>" & ErrorArray(2, 1) & "</td><td>-</td><td>-</td>" & _
            "</tr>" & _
            "<tr>" & _
                "<th>ICP</th><th>Error Field in payload</th><th>Expected Value</th><th>Re-trigger required (Y/N)</th><th>Notes</th>" & _
            "</tr>" & _
            "<tr>" & _
                "<td>" & Range("D4").Value & "</td><td>" & ErrorArray(1, 2) & "</td><td>" & ErrorArray(2, 2) & "</td><td>-</td><td>-</td>" & _
            "</tr></table><style>" & _
        "th, td {" & _
                "text-align: left; padding: 5px; border-collapse: collapse; border:0}" & _
        "<p>Kind regards,<br></p></style></body></html>"

    End If

    On Error Resume Next
        With OutlookMail
        .To = "Email@Email.com" 
        .CC = "Email@Email.com"
        .Subject = "ICP " & Range("D4").Value & " - Query"
        .Display
        .HTMLBody = strBody & .HTMLBody
        End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutlookMail = Nothing
    Set OutlookApp = Nothing

    End Sub
```

Comment: Which line does the code stop on when it errors?

Comment: Oh sorry should've mentioned this. So if there are 0 errors then I get the 'out of range' error at:
ReDim ErrorArray(1 To 2, 1 To NumberOfErrors)

If there is 1 error then it all works fine. If there are 2 errors then I get the same error at:
"<p>Kind regards,<br></p></style></body></html>"
- This is the bottom line of "Elseif NumberOfErrors = 2 Then"

Comment: What does stepping through the code in the debugger tell you? *subscript out of range* means that you're exceeding the bounds of the array. Use the debugger to find out why. And clearly (based on your comment) it's an error to run any  of the error array-related code if there are zero errors, so you've already identified the problem. The code from the `ReDim` comment on should only be executed if there is at least one error, so you need to protect it with an `if` block.

Comment: @KenWhite, the debugger tells me different lines of interest depending on the value of NumberOfErrors. Check my previous comment above :) I've added an IF block for the 'Redim' section and now it gives an error for 0 NumberOfErrors at:

For i = 1 To UBound(ErrorArray, 2)
    If ErrorArray(1, i) = "" Then
        i = UBound(ErrorArray, 2)
        ReDim Preserve ErrorArray(1 To 2, 1 To i - 1)
    End If
Next i

Comment: Read what I wrote again. *t's an error to run any of the error array-related code if there are zero errors*. **None** of the array-related code  **starting before the ReDim** should be executed if there are zero errors. **NONE** of it - I didn't say *only the ReDim line should be protected*, I said **All of the code starting before the `ReDim` to the end**.

Comment: If `NumberOfErrors` is zero, then when you `ReDim` you are trying to `ReDim ErrorArray(1 To 2, 1 To 0)` - which of course will error as you can't have `1 To 0`..? That's causing the error 9 you're seeing. This is regardless of further code that Ken points out shouldn't be running.